# UILabel subclass doesn't show text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, subclass

I've subclassed UILabel class to override `drawRect:` method. The label in IB is connected with the created subclass. It appears on the screen, but it doesn't show any text, whether it it is set in IB or programmatically. The label itself appears on the screen, when I'm logging it's `text` property, it shows OK.

Here's my code:

MyLabel.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyLabel : UILabel
@end
```

MyLabel.m

```
#import "MyLabel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation MyLabel


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: .1f alpha: 5.f];
    UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: .3f alpha: 5.f];
    UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: .5f alpha: 5.f];
    UIColor *innerGlow = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.f alpha: .25f];

    NSArray *gradientColors = @[(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor];
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) gradientColors,  NULL);

    CGFloat bWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat bHeight = self.frame.size.height;

    UIBezierPath *roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:    CGRectMake(0, 0, bWidth, bHeight)
                                                                cornerRadius: 0];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];

    CGGradientRef background = gradient;

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, background, CGPointMake(bWidth / 2.f, 0), CGPointMake(bWidth / 2.f, bHeight), 0);

    [borderColor setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 6;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];

    CGFloat glowRadius = 3.f;
    UIBezierPath *innerGlowRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(glowRadius, glowRadius, bWidth - 2 * glowRadius, bHeight - 2 * glowRadius)   cornerRadius: 0];
    [innerGlow setStroke];
    innerGlowRect.lineWidth = 3;
    [innerGlowRect stroke];

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}

@end
```

Maybe I need to override `drawTextInRect:` method, but I don't know how.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call:

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```

At the top or your drawRect: method. If you need more control over how the string looks you'll need to draw it your self with the [NSString string drawing methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, this works great! Thank you! I knew that you shouldn't call super method if you are subclassing UIView, but missed that the superclass is UILabel

Comment: @NikitaShytyk why wouldn't you call super on UIView subclasses, and your classes super class may be UILabel, but UILabel's super class is UIView.

Comment: I am trying with IBDesignable for uilabel subclass, and override drawRect like this, but no text appear even when I already put [super drawRect:rect];. What is wrong?